# Cannot boot old dell computer

Tags: boot, hardware

I have an old Dell computer. When I try to boot it from a usb stick into `Manjaro i3` I get this error:

```
initramfs failed: write error
```

### System specs:

- System: **Dell DXP051**

#### Processor

- Processor Type **Intel® Pentium 4 CPU 3.00GHz**
- Processor Clock Speed **3.0GHz**
- Processor Bus Speed: **800 MHz**
- Processor L2 Cache **2MB**
- Processor L3 Cache **0**
- Processor ID **0F43**
- Multiple Core Capable: **No**
- Hyperthreading Capable: **Yes**
- 64-bit Technology **Yes (Intel EM64T)**

#### Memory

- Installed Memory **512 MB**
- Memory Speed **533 MHz**
- Memory Channel Mode **Dual Interleaved**
- Memory Technology **DDR2 SDRAM**

I have googled it for days now, and have found nothing.

Comment: First thing I would try is memtest86+ and ensure the RAM is OK.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I already tried that. Memory seemed to be fine.

Comment: have you tried another linux distro ? or this stick in another computer?

Comment: @Cellcore I also tried Tinycore with success.

Comment: tried the 32bit version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Legacy version of [Bodhi Linux](http://bodhilinux.com/download) will work even if you don't have PAE.